# To get the selected index for multiple dropdowns of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple dropdowns with the same class but different values. On change of a dropdown selected value, I need to know the index. Below is my following code:

```js
$("body").on("change", ".ddlFruit", function () {
    var fruitIndex = $(".ddlFruit option:selected").index();
    alert(fruitIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Bannana</option>
      <option value="3">Mango</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Water Melon</option>
      <option value="2">Kiwi</option>
      <option value="3">Peach</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Strawberry</option>
      <option value="2">Papaya</option>
      <option value="3">Grapes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue with this is it always gives the index of the first dropdown even if I change values in second or third dropdown. I tried something like

```
var fruitIndex = $("this option:selected").index();
```

but that does not work. How do I figure out the right index in Jquery without having to change anything in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `this` context as the [second argument in the jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context).

```
var fruitIndex = $("option:selected", this).index();
```

```js
$("body").on("change", ".ddlFruit", function () {
    var fruitIndex = $("option:selected", this).index();
    alert(fruitIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Bannana</option>
      <option value="3">Mango</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Water Melon</option>
      <option value="2">Kiwi</option>
      <option value="3">Peach</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Strawberry</option>
      <option value="2">Papaya</option>
      <option value="3">Grapes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get element within `this` context.

```
var fruitIndex = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
```

```js
$("body").on("change", ".ddlFruit", function () {
    var fruitIndex = $(this).find("option:selected").index();
    alert(fruitIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Bannana</option>
      <option value="3">Mango</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Water Melon</option>
      <option value="2">Kiwi</option>
      <option value="3">Peach</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control ddlFruit">
      <option value="1">Strawberry</option>
      <option value="2">Papaya</option>
      <option value="3">Grapes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```